# How to make Semantic error message outside of form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one problem. I have to make my error messages display outside of form, but I have no idea how to make it, because my javascript is displaying messages, when the error message class is inside in the form. is it possible to make it outside of form?
This is picture, how it looks. In this example I want to display errors below the red button.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlIXv.png)

```
               <form class="ui form" id="companyForm" style="margin-top:1em">
                  <div class="two fields">
                    <div class="field">
                      <input type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Company name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <input type="text" name="companyCode" placeholder="Company code">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                      <input type="text" name="companyAddress" placeholder="Company address">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui error message"></div>
               </form>
               <div class="ui bottom attached red button" onclick="submitForm(this);">
               <p><b>Place order</b> <i class="large shop icon"></i></p>
               </div>
               <div class="ui error message"></div>


function submitForm(){


var formValidationRules2 =
  {
    companyName: {
    identifier: 'companyName',
    rules: [
       {
        type   : 'minLength[2]',
        prompt : 'Your Company name must be at least {ruleValue} characters'
      }
    ]
  },
    companyCode: {
    identifier: 'companyCode',
    rules: [
       {
        type   : 'minLength[4]',       
        prompt : 'Your Company code must be at least {ruleValue} characters'
      }
    ]
  },
    companyAddress: {
    identifier: 'companyAddress',
    rules: [
       {
        type   : 'minLength[10]',
        prompt : 'Your Company address must be at least {ruleValue} characters'
      }
    ]
  }
  }

  $("#companyForm").form(formValidationRules2);
  $("#companyForm").form('validate form');

 if($("#companyForm").form('is valid')){
 joooo();
 }

}
```

Comment: can you share a working fiddle?

Comment: Use <div class="ui error message" id="ui error message"></div> then  document.getElementById("ui error message").innerHTML = prompt;

Comment: @user3344236 thanks, it helped :)